# log4j не показывает error красным цветом

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j

Использую spring настроил логирование, есть два вопроса.

1. Почему он не показывает error красным цветом все показывает как и Info.
2. Как я могу настроить чтобы к примеру Логи от spring показывал error а только мои логи показывала error

Сейчас настройка такая:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{1}:%M:%L - %m%n

# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, stdout

# Log all JDBC parameters
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL, stdout

    log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment=info

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl=all
```

еще есть файл common-logging.properties

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

Сейчас последняя версия настроена так

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%M:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.kz=warn, stderr

log4j.appender.stderr.target=System.err
log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.stderr.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%M:%L - %m%n

#Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info, stdout

#Log all JDBC parameters 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=warn
log4j.appender.Spring=stdout
    #log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl=all
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.contextr=info, stdout
#log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext=info, stdout
```

Comment: Мне кажется, во втором вопросе есть логическое противоречие. По крайней мере, не могу понять, где как надо чтобы показывало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное вот это убрать:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
```

Т.к. это означает всё что выкидывается на уровне info (и выше) валить в stdout и написать как-то так:

```
log4j.logger.com.my.app=info, stdout
```

Что значит красным error. Это ведь просто лог.
Если вы имеете в веду подсветку в IDE, то там std error подсвечивается, можно настроить логер отдельный:

```
log4j.appender.stderr.target=System.err
```

Ну и писать туда, только ошибки на уровне error:

```
log4j.logger.com.my.app=error, stderr
```

Comment: > выкидывается на уровне info  /br

Это я имел введу:  /br

     LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class).info("Log log log...")

Comment: когда убрал эту строку мои личные логи не показывает, которые я задаю показывать в коде

Comment: при добавлении 
log4j.logger.kz.tanikin=error, stderr

log4j.appender.stderr.target=System.err

log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

#log4j.appender.stderr.target=System.out

log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stderr.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{1}:%M:%L - %m%n

Остальные поля оставил не тронутыми
Теперь показывает только error

Comment: Ну это логично, настроен всего один апендер.
Если хотите ещё логи, то добавьте второй апендер, который в stdout писать будет или в файл или ещё куда-нибудь.

Comment: в коде пишу 
logger.error(username );
он показывает  его два раза, один раз красным а другой нормальный, как можно сделать так чтобы error шло только на stderr, а на stdout шло только Info

Comment: @JTan
Думаю можно попробовать
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.stdout.levelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.stdout.levelMax=WARN

Но в самом деле это совсем не так должно работать, должен быть более подробный лог и менее (т.е. иерархия не просто так существует)

Comment: добавил эти фильтры выходит ошибка log4j:WARN Missing class definition for filter: [log4j.appender.stdout.filter.stdout], и еще я не понял что вы имеете ввиду определенный лог и менее, я просто хочу, показывать INFO но иногда если будет какая то ошибка она подсвечивала мне его красным, или я что то не так делаю, объясните как мне можно логировать и смотреть как все это работает.

Comment: Согласен с фильтром надо как-то так попробовать:
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.LevelToMatch=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.AcceptOnMatch=TRUE

Вот в этом примере как раз ваш случай
https://github.com/janinko/Log4J-configuration-converter/blob/master/log4j.properties